# Fast Report displaying incorrect data from ADOQuery

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I have a problem with Fast Report displaying incorrect data from an ADOquery. I use the following sql.text

```
SELECT * FROM JOB_DATA 
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ON JOB_DATA.CUST_CODE = CUSTOMER.CUST_CODE 
WHERE JOB_DATA.SHIP_DATE Between [Date1] And [Date2] 
ORDER by SHIP_DATE
```

Fast Report only shows the data where SHIP_DATE = null.

If I throw up a TDBgrid and attach it to a data source attached to the same ADOquery, then the dbgrid shows exactly the correct information.

I'm out of ideas, any suggestions?

To answer questions about where the dates come from:

```
var
  date1:string;
  date2:string;
  sql_str:string;
begin
  date1:=inputbox('Date Range','Enter Beginning Date','');
  Try
    StrToDate(date1);
  Except 
    On EConvertError Do
    Begin
      MessageDlg('Please enter a valid date.  Format xx/xx/xx',
         mtError, [mbOK], 0);
      //ShowMessage('Please enter a valid date.  Format `enter code here`xx/xx/xx');
      Exit;
    End;
  End;

  date2:=inputbox('Date Range','Enter Ending Date','');
  Try
    StrToDate(date2);
  Except 
    On EConvertError Do
    Begin
      MessageDlg('Please enter a valid date.  Format xx/xx/xx',
          mtError, [mbOK], 0);
      //ShowMessage('Please enter a valid date.  Format `enter code here`xx/xx/xx');
      Exit;
    End;
  End;

  sql_str:= 'SELECT * FROM JOB_DATA INNER JOIN CUSTOMER ON ' +
            'JOB_DATA.CUST_CODE = CUSTOMER.CUST_CODE ' +
            'WHERE JOB_DATA.SHIP_DATE Between ';
  sql_str:= sql_str+ ''' ';
  sql_st:=sql_str + date1;
  sql_str:= sql_str+ '''';
  sql_str:= sql_str+ ' AND ';
  sql_str:= sql_str+ ''' ';
  sql_str:= sql_str+ date2;
  sql_str:= sql_str+ ' ''';

  with ADOQuery5 do 
  begin
    Close;
    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.text:= sql_str;
    Open;
  end;
  frxreport2.ShowReport();
end;
```

The ADOquery is attached to frxDBDataset2 which is attached to frxReport2. I am doing nothing to alter the results in the query.

No, I have no code in the report, it was all generated from the wizard.

Comment: How are you connecting the report to the data? FR only shows what your query contains, unless you're doing something to change that yourself. Where do `Date1` and `Date2` come from? Your question says FR is doing something wrong, but you're providing no information about FR at all; you've just shown a query and said "FR displays incorrect data" with no details that we can use to try and help you.

Comment: The ADOquery is attached to frxDBDataset2 attached to frxreport2 I get the dates from date1:=inputbox('Date Range','Enter Beginning Date','');

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add any additional details there, so we don't have to pick them out from the comments and they can be properly formatted. That's only half of the information. How does the `date1` get from the line you showed to a part of the query? It just doesn't appear there because you got a value from `inputbox`. Do you have any code that's part of the report itself at all? If you want help, *provide the details* that will allow us to help. Please don't make us beg for every scrap of information.

Comment: The report was generated entirely from the wizard. I wrote no code inside FR. No matter what date range I enter FR only shows data where SHIP_DATE = null, but the dbgrid shows the date range correctly.

Comment: I've posted an answer that may help. If it doesn't, at least you can update your code to be more readable. :-) (When you post code here, you should format it properly so we can read it. Clicking the little orange button labeled `?` shows you how, and you can preview it right below where you're entering it as you do so that you'll know it looks correct. If we can't read it, it's much harder to help. I got you started by fixing the last code you posted.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FastReport cannot display records only where `SHIP_DATE` is `NULL`, because your query shouldn't be returning them based on your `WHERE` clause if `Date1` and `Date2` are properly assigned. This means that either your dataset and the FastReport aren't connected properly or that something in your code assigning the date values for the `BETWEEN` clause is wrong, and the dates aren't being provided to the query correctly.

The first place to start looking is to make sure that all of the report columns are correctly assigned the proper `TfrxDataSet` and the proper database column. (Click on the report item (text object or whatever it might be), and check its `DataSet` and `DataField` properties to ensure they are correct.)

If that's not the problem, it may be the way you're building your query, which probably isn't correctly formatting the dates for ADO. (You're just using whatever format happens to pass the `StrToDate` calls without raising an exception.)

The way you're setting up your SQL is really unadviseable. It's unreadable and unmaintainable when you try to manage quoting yourself in code.

You should use parameters, which first and foremost protects you against SQL injection, but also allows the database driver to properly format quoted values and dates for you and keeps things readable. (You can also use readable names for the parameters, so that when you see them six months from now you'll know what they mean.)

```
var
  // Your other variable declarations here
  StartDate, EndDate: TDateTime;
begin
  Date1 := InputBox(Whatever);
  try
    StartDate := StrToDate(Date1);
  except
    // Handle EConvertError
  end;
  Date2 := InputBox(Whatever);
  try
    EndDate := StrToDate(Date2);
  except
    // Handle EConvertError
  end;

  sql_str := 'SELECT * FROM JOB_DATA J'#13 +
             'INNER JOIN CUSTOMER C'#13 +
             'ON J.CUST_CODE = C.CUST_CODE'#13 +
             'WHERE J.SHIP_DATE BETWEEN :StartDate AND :EndDate';

  with ADOQuery5 do 
  begin
    Close;
    // No need to clear. If you're using the same query more than once,
    // move the SQL assignment and the Parameter.DataType somewhere
    // else, and don't set them here.
    // The query can be reused just by closing, changing parameter values,
    // and reopening.
    SQL.Text := sql_str;
    with Parameters.ParamByName('StartDate') do
    begin
      DataType := ftDate;
      Value := StartDate;
    end;
    with Parameters.ParamByName('EndDate') do
    begin
      DataType := ftDate;
      Value := EndDate;
    end;
    Open;
  end;
  frxReport2.ShowReport;
end;
```

Comment: Ken, Thanks, but still the same results. The dbgrid I put on the form for testing shows the records in the date range requested, while the report only shows the records where SHIP_DATE=null. Could it be a bug in my version of FR?

Comment: I don't see how. If you've done nothing in code to change anything, FR only displays what's in the query results. If you're seeing null `SHIP_DATE` values, you've got something wrong in your query. Try keeping the DBGrid connected and doing the `ShowReport` at the same time, size the report preview so that you can see the grid and report at the same time. What do you see when you compare them? Are you sure the FR is displaying the `SHIP_DATE` from the data? (Could you have missed connecting the report column to the query column?)

Comment: Ken, Thanks, your comment about the report column being connected to the query column helped. Not sure why, but the report kept jumping to frxDBDataset1 instead of staying attached to frxDBDataset2. Not sure why, but I deleted the frxReport2 and started it over and it works now.

Comment: I added a new paragraph (currently the second one) to mention making sure that things are correctly connected. :-)

Answer (score 0):

When I start having problems with ADO, I log the information.

You'll need to create your own logger...but here's the jest of it...Note it will log the parameter values that are being passed to the query, including the SQL.

```
procedure TLogger.SetUpConnectionLogging(aParent: TComponent);
var
  a_Index: integer;
begin
  for a_Index := 0 to aParent.ComponentCount - 1 do
    if aParent.Components[a_Index] is TAdoConnection then
    begin
      TAdoConnection(aParent.Components[a_Index]).OnWillExecute :=  WillExecute;
      TAdoConnection(aParent.Components[a_Index]).OnExecuteComplete :=  ExecuteComplete;
    end;
end;

procedure TLogger.ExecuteComplete(Connection: TADOConnection;
  RecordsAffected: Integer; const Error: Error; var EventStatus: TEventStatus;
  const Command: _Command; const Recordset: _Recordset);
var
  a_Index: integer;
begin
  AddLog('AdoConnection ExecuteComplete', True);
  AddLog('Execution In MilliSeconds', IntToStr(MilliSecondsBetween(Time, FDif)));
  AddLog('Execution In Seconds', IntToStr(SecondsBetween (Time, FDif)));
  AddLog('Execution In Minutes', IntToStr(MinutesBetween (Time, FDif)));
  AddLog('CommandText', Command.CommandText);
  if Assigned(Command) then
  begin
    AddLog('Param Count', IntToStr(Command.Parameters.Count));
    for a_Index := 0 to Command.Parameters.Count - 1 do
    begin
      AddLog(Command.Parameters.Item[a_Index].Name, VarToWideStr(Command.Parameters.Item[a_Index].Value));
    end;
    AddLog('CommandType', GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TCommandType),Integer(Command.CommandType)));
  end;
  AddLog('EventStatus', GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TEventStatus),Integer(EventStatus)));
  if Assigned(RecordSet) then
  begin
    AddLog('CursorType', GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TCursorType),Integer(Recordset.CursorType)));
    AddLog('LockType',  GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TADOLockType),Integer(Recordset.LockType)));
  end;
  AddLog('RecordsAffected',  IntToStr(RecordsAffected));
  AddLog('AdoConnection ExecuteComplete', False);
end; 

procedure TLogger.WillExecute(Connection: TADOConnection;
  var CommandText: WideString; var CursorType: TCursorType;
  var LockType: TADOLockType; var CommandType: TCommandType;
  var ExecuteOptions: TExecuteOptions; var EventStatus: TEventStatus;
  const Command: _Command; const Recordset: _Recordset);
begin
  AddLog('Connection WillExecute', True);
  AddLog('Connection Name', Connection.Name);
  AddLog('CommandText', CommandText);
  AddLog('CommandType', GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TCommandType),Integer(CommandType)));
  AddLog('EventStatus', GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TEventStatus),Integer(EventStatus)));
  AddLog('CursorType', GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TCursorType),Integer(CursorType)));
  AddLog('Connection WillExecute', False);
  FDif :=  Time;
end;
```

Comment: How does this answer the question asked about why FastReports isn't displaying the expected values?

Comment: @Ken White it allows you to know what SQL the report is running...You can confirm the underlying dataset that the report is running,  is correct and not something you assume is right...